Fix position of an image while using elementor pro gallary widget
I have image gallery built with Elementor Pro Gallery widget. I have set it show images in random positions every time I refresh the page. Now I want one of the images to always show in one specific position on every page load while rest of the images shuffle positions.
Is there any way to do that.
For example I want image 1 to always show at row 1 col 1.


You'll have to ask Elementor's support about this. Third-party plugin and theme questions are off topic here.

Plugin has no solution for this. I am looking for a custom CSS/JS solution. It's using  "display: grid" CSS property to list the images.

@atif it was a test of ringo media

@AHSANKHAN lol, yes. Did you figure this out and, did you hear back from them ?

@Atif I did that using php & css ,css order is used, did not hear back from them yet
